# Scope Function Implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, kotlin-android-extensions

what is the specific purpose of Scope function in android Kotlin. where we practically implemented.Any one can discuss in detail i have red documentation from below mentioned link

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#function-selection

although there is defined in details a key difference. (Let, with , run) return Lambda result so where we will use "let","run" and "with"

three of them return lambda result same rest of two return Context object so why we prefer to each of them that which of them is best in which case

Comment: check this https://blog.mindorks.com/using-scoped-functions-in-kotlin-let-run-with-also-apply

Comment: as the previous colleague commented, I think that link will be objective.

Comment: Amazingly, this doesn't seem to be a duplicate question as far as I can tell from searching. But this is the topic of a thousand Medium articles written by people who just grasped the topic. Anyway, it is hard to answer objectively, because their use is a matter of choice. Opinion-based questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.